# Шифрование sharedpreferences - есть ли смысл задуматься на эту тему?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

В своем приложении я использую самые разнообразные настройки `SharedPreferences` которые используются повсеместно во всем приложении. Сама программа создана чтобы развернуть веб-сервис на мобильном устройстве. В настройках у меня есть много каких "секретных" данных. Честно говоря я не уверен, что если человек без должного уровня своих знаний получит к этим настройкам доступ, то он сможет как-то их использовать. Но вот если какой-то умелец все-таки сможет получить доступ к данным в обход программы то я думаю что это не есть хорошо. Например, в этих настройках у меня есть адрес сервера, токены которые я туда сохраняю - это та информация к которой я думаю что не нужно получать никому доступ.

Вообще получить доступ к этой информации можно, если у вас есть рут-права на телефоне. Вот я через студию и через рутованный телефон смог найти эти данные. Вот у меня возник вопрос - нужно может начинать копать в сторону шифрования данных которые сохраняются на мобильном устройстве, и если все-таки нужно, то как это лучше всего реализовать.

Надеюсь я не первый кого озаботил этот вопрос, и найдется тот кто сможет мне помочь. Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: приложение работает с сетью? Храните данные на сервере, как вариант

Comment: да приложение работает с сетью, но например для отправки запроса на сервер нужен адрес сервера, который хранится в настройках, или например два токена у меня есть, они и так есть на сервере, но в приложении они используются для получения доступа к информации или обновлению токена.

Comment: Там, где есть шифрование есть и дешифратор, просто не нужно на клиенте ничего хранить важного и все будет ок.

Comment: @And, не очень понимаю пока что если честно, вот например после получения пары токенов я их сохраняю, и я их могу потом найти в файлах, адрес сервера тоже хранится на устройстве, логика приложения такова, что у меня постоянно тянется из настроек все эти три переменные, это я думаю довольно важная информация, но я не знаю как хранить эту информацию на сервере и получать без токена, и как обратится к серверу, адреса которого у меня нету, так как он на самом сервере? просто мне сложно представить это)

Comment: Где логика? Как спрятав адрес, вы обратитесь к нему? Его не нужно прятать. Просто нужно при каждом входе юзверя, генерить например новые токены.

Comment: Этим занимается сервер))) он мне кидает токены в случае удачного запроса

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, автор хочет, чтобы только его приложение смогло, используя токен общаться с сервером, то есть даже если кто-то в обход приложения получил информацию об адресе сервера и токен, не смог этой информацией воспользоваться. Потому как, токен выдается сервером клиенту, и дальше уже дело клиента, как его хранить и что с ним делать. В браузерах также есть возможность посмотреть токен клиента. Другой вопрос, как обеспечить использование выданного токена только вашим приложением? Тут уже нужно думать, как вариант выдавать токены с истекающим сроком действия, проверка на сервере.

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin, вы совершенно правы)) эти два токена которые я получаю, истекают. У них совершенно разные строки действия, поэтому у меня есть специально созданная функция для обновления токенов.